# Draw a shadow border on ModalView with kivy Vertex Instruction?

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, trigonometry, kivy-language, vertex

I am trying to draw a shadow for a `ModalView` using the `Canvas` `Line`  vertex instructions.  I.e. the `ModalView` bottom and left sides should have a slight shadowy overlay when open.  I have tried calling the `ModalView` property `overlay_color` with no effect and `Canvas` `Line`  vertex instructions do not create the right effect.  But I cannot seem to only draw a bottom and left border that gives the shadowy effect.

```
<PopScrollModal>
    on_open: app.root._is_modal_open = True
    on_dismiss: app.root._is_modal_open = False
    id: popscroll
    auto_dismiss: True
    orientation: 'vertical'
    size_hint: (0.94, 0.41)
    border: [50, 50, 16, 16]
    overlay_color: [0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.4]
    pos_hint: {'top': 0.72}
    background_normal: ''
    background_color: (1, 1, 1, 0)
    background: 'white.png'
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba: app.theme_cls.bg_dark
        RoundedRectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos
            radius: [7,]
    canvas.after:
        Color:
            rgba: (0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.4)
        Line:
            width: 1.
            rounded_rectangle: (self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height, 7)
    RecycleView:
        id: view_popscroll
        viewclass: 'PopScrollBut'
        pos_hint: {'top': 1}
        size_hint: [1, 0.99]
        do_scroll_y: True
        RecycleGridLayout:
            cols: 1
            spacing: 1
            default_size: None, 70
            default_size_hint: 1, None
            size_hint: 1, None
            size: self.minimum_size
```

This line instruction draws on the bottom but does not adhere to the radius of the canvas:

```
canvas.after:
        Color:
            rgba: (0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.4)
        Line:
            width: 1.
            close: False
            points: self.pos[0], self.pos[1], self.pos[0] + self.size[0], self.pos[1]]
```

The `Line` instruction only draws a line around the `ModalView`.
Can somebody help to understand how to set the `Points` so they only appear left and bottom or set the `overlay_color` in the same way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that using `BorderImage`. It is not well documented and difficult to understand how it is actually intended to work. But here is an example that mostly does what you want:

```
class MyPop(Popup):
    pass

kv = '''
<MyPop>:
    canvas.before:
        BorderImage:
            source: 'shadow32.png'
            border: 30, 0, 0, 30
            pos: self.x - 30, self.y - 30
            size: self.width + 60, self.height + 60
'''
```

And here is the `shadow32.png` that is used above:

[image]

Comment: Extraordinary! Here I was polishing of my trig books with the view to understand the `Points` property and once again @John Anderson you make a complication seem so simple.  Thanks... again!